# Pandas: Заменить значения в массиве данных с одного на другое

Tags: python, массивы, excel, pandas

Есть вопрос, как в массиве заменить значения на нужные?Хочу если в массиве значение 9999, то заменить ее на 1, а остальные заменить на 0.
из эксель [файла](http://dropmefiles.com/gDWmK) создается другой файл.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = r'C:\Users\fazliakhmetovRV\Documents\Python Scripts\primer1.xlsx'
out = r'C:\Users\fazliakhmetovRV\Documents\Python Scripts\result.xlsx'

cols = ['metka','x','y','z','gk']

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname='er', skiprows=4, header=None, parse_cols='C:XFD')

dfs = []

for i in range(df.columns.size//5):
    lbl_col = 5*i
    # filter each 5-column block
    x = df.ix[(df[lbl_col] != 0) & (df[lbl_col] != 9999), lbl_col:lbl_col+4]
    # set custom column names
    x.columns = cols
    # set 'metka' column as index (will be used for alignment by `pd.concat()`) 
    x.index = x.metka
    dfs.append(x)

# merge filtered DFs horizontally (aligned by indexes)
result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# replace all `metka` columns with the "most complete" list of labels
result.ix[:, ::5] = pd.concat([result.index.to_series()] * (len(df.columns)//5), axis=1)
# replace all NaN's with `9999`
result.fillna(9999, inplace=True)
# save resulting DF to Excel
result.to_excel(out, index=False)
```

Из result.xlsx данные пишутся в массивы:

```
n_met=len(result)
n_well=result.columns.size/5
x=result.x.values.astype(int)
y=result.y.values.astype(int)
z=result.z.values.astype(int)
gk=result.gk.values.astype(float)
```

Далее хочу заменить значения с 9999 на 1, а остальные 0.
Как я понимаю, так это делать нельзя):

```
for i in range(1,n_met):
    for j in range(1,n_well):
        if x[i][j]==9999:
            x[i][j]=1
        else:
            x[i][j]=0
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать этот момент?

[image: частичное заполнение таблицы выклиниваний]

Comment: Вы можете выложить пример ожидаемого результата? Замену вы хотите делать только в столбце `x`? PS не совсем понятно зачем вы создали все эти переменные: `x`, `y`, `z`, `gk`...

Comment: @MaxU Получаются отдельные массивы из result по x,y,z,gk. И по ним нужно сделать отдельные массивы с 1 вместо 9999, и 0 вместо остальных значений.Прикрепил к описанию фото с алгоритмом.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите поменять значения на `1` и `0`во всех столбцах, кроме `metka`?

Answer (score 2):

сделать замену можно без всяких циклов:

```
r = result.copy()
r.loc[:, r.columns[~r.columns.str.contains('^metka')]] = \
    np.where(r[r.columns[~r.columns.str.contains('^metka')]] == 9999, 1, 0)

In [53]: r
Out[53]:
    metka  x  y  z  gk  metka.1  x.1  y.1  z.1  gk.1  ...    metka.17  x.17  y.17  z.17  gk.17  metka.18  x.18  y.18  z.18  gk.18
0       1  0  0  0   0        1    0    0    0     0  ...           1     0     0     0      0         1     0     0     0      0
1       2  0  0  0   0        2    0    0    0     0  ...           2     0     0     0      0         2     0     0     0      0
2       3  1  1  1   1        3    0    0    0     0  ...           3     0     0     0      0         3     0     0     0      0
3       4  0  0  0   0        4    0    0    0     0  ...           4     0     0     0      0         4     0     0     0      0
4       5  0  0  0   0        5    0    0    0     0  ...           5     0     0     0      0         5     0     0     0      0
5       6  0  0  0   0        6    1    1    1     1  ...           6     0     0     0      0         6     0     0     0      0
6       7  0  0  0   0        7    0    0    0     0  ...           7     0     0     0      0         7     0     0     0      0
7       8  0  0  0   0        8    0    0    0     0  ...           8     0     0     0      0         8     0     0     0      0
8       9  0  0  0   0        9    0    0    0     0  ...           9     0     0     0      0         9     0     0     0      0
9      10  0  0  0   0       10    0    0    0     0  ...          10     0     0     0      0        10     0     0     0      0
10     11  0  0  0   0       11    0    0    0     0  ...          11     0     0     0      0        11     0     0     0      0
11     12  0  0  0   0       12    0    0    0     0  ...          12     0     0     0      0        12     0     0     0      0
12     13  0  0  0   0       13    0    0    0     0  ...          13     0     0     0      0        13     0     0     0      0
13     14  1  1  1   1       14    0    0    0     0  ...          14     0     0     0      0        14     0     0     0      0
14     15  1  1  1   1       15    0    0    0     0  ...          15     0     0     0      0        15     0     0     0      0
15     16  1  1  1   1       16    0    0    0     0  ...          16     1     1     1      1        16     1     1     1      1
16     17  1  1  1   1       17    1    1    1     1  ...          17     1     1     1      1        17     1     1     1      1

[17 rows x 95 columns]
```

PS по поводу вашего эскиза, который вы выложили - это все относительно легко делается средствами Pandas, но для этого надо иметь тестовые данные и представлять как должен выглядеть результат (хотя бы несколько строк).